# Text Method doesn't work with Findclass(...) but with plain "TEdit"

Tags: delphi, delphi-2005

I want to use findclass and findcomponent to be able to pass the sender component as parameter in a procedure.

Thank you for reading.

Edit: I use Delphi 2005

---

> [Error]: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'text'

```
TestMemo.Text := (FindComponent(VonKomponente.name) as
  (Findclass(vonkomponente.ClassType.ClassName))).text; -> does not work

TestMemo.Text := (FindComponent(VonKomponente.name) as TEdit).text; -> works
```

---

```
procedure TFormTest.Edit7DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MemoEdit((Sender as TComponent),'table','row');
end;


procedure TFormTest.MemoEdit(VonKomponente :TComponent;table,row : String);
begin
  FormTestMemo.Max_Textlaenge := get_length(table,row);
  FormTestMemo.Text := (FindComponent(VonKomponente.name) as
    (Findclass(vonkomponente.ClassType.ClassName))).text;
  If FormTestMemo.Showmodal = MrOk then
  begin
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: FindClass returns a TPersistentClass which doesn't have any Text. You probably want to use RTTI.

Comment: Look at the source code of TMemo.  It doesn't have a `Text` property.  It has a `Lines` property which in turn has a `Text` one, so you can write `Memo1.Lines.Text := 'Hello'`.  Also, you can't call  `ShowModal` on `TestMemo` if `TestMemo` is of type  `TMemo`.

Comment: TestMemo is a Form. Max_Textlaenge and Text are public variables. Sorry i will edit.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - I understand the point with the TPersistentClass now. But how do i use RTTI for a better result? Thank you.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Working_with_RTTI

Comment: @Sertac: Poster is using D2005. Tokyo RTTI won't help. They'll need TypInfo style RTTI instead.

Comment: @Ken thanks! Huppel, refer to [here](http://www.blong.com/conferences/borconuk98/delphirtti/cb140.htm), although old, it is more fun than the official [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.TypInfo). I can't find any conceptual topics in the official documentation.

Comment: @Sertac: I couldn't find anything in the official docs either, but didn't have much time to look.

Comment: @KenWhite - thank you

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - thank you as well, you got me into the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.  You cannot pass a metaclass type determined at runtime to the `as` operator.

For what you are trying to do, you will have to resort to using old-style RTTI via the [`TypInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo) unit, in this case the [`TypInfo.GetStrProp()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TypInfo.GetStrProp) function, eg:

```
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

FormTestMemo.Text := GetStrProp(VonKomponente, 'Text');
```

Note that not all text-based components have a `Text` property, some have a `Caption` property, eg:

```
uses
  ..., TypInfo;

var
  prop: PPropInfo;

prop := GetPropInfo(VonKomponente, 'Text');
if prop = nil then
  prop := GetPropInfo(VonKomponente, 'Caption');

if prop <> nil then
  FormTestMemo.Text := GetStrProp(VonKomponente, prop)
else
  FormTestMemo.Text := '';
```